# Groupby Apply Filter without Lambda

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have this data:

```
data = {
    'batch_no': [42, 42, 52, 52, 52, 73],     
    'quality': ['OK', 'NOT OK', 'OK', 'NOT OK', 'NOT OK', 'OK'], 
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['batch_no', 'quality'])
```

This gives me the following dataframe

```
batch_no    quality
42          OK
42          NOT OK
52          OK
52          NOT OK
52          NOT OK
73          OK
```

Now I need to find the count of `NOT OK` for each `batch_no`.

I can achieve this using `groupby` and `apply` with a `lamda` function as follows:

```
df.groupby('batch_no')['quality'].apply(lambda x: x[x.eq('NOT OK')].count())
```

This gives me the following desired output

```
batch_no
42              1
52              2
73              0
```

However this is extremely slow even on my moderate sized data of around 3 million rows and is not feasible for my needs.

Is there a fast alternative to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare column `quality`, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `batch_no` and aggregate `sum`, `True`s are processes like `1` so it count values:

```
df = df['quality'].eq('NOT OK')
                  .groupby(df['batch_no']).sum()
                  .astype(int)
                  .reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
   batch_no  count
0        42      1
1        52      2
2        73      0
```

Detail:

```
print (df['quality'].eq('NOT OK'))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: quality, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
In [77]: df.quality.eq('NOT OK').groupby(df.batch_no).sum()
Out[77]:
batch_no
42    1.0
52    2.0
73    0.0
Name: quality, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

This will provide all value count

```
df.groupby('batch_no').quality.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[231]: 
quality   NOT OK  OK
batch_no            
42             1   1
52             2   1
73             0   1
```

Using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.batch_no,df.quality)
Out[242]: 
quality   NOT OK  OK
batch_no            
42             1   1
52             2   1
73             0   1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.batch_no)
pd.Series(np.bincount(f, df.quality.eq('NOT OK')).astype(int), u)

42    1
52    2
73    0
dtype: int64
```

---

Incorporating `'OK'` (inspired by Wen)

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.batch_no)
j = df.quality.eq('NOT OK')

pd.DataFrame(
    np.bincount(i * 2 + j, minlength=len(r) * 2).reshape(len(r), -1),
    r, ['OK', 'NOT OK']
)

    OK  NOT OK
42   1       1
52   1       2
73   1       0
```